# When I am trying to increment a variable, unable to compare the variable with values in dictionary

Tags: robotframework

Suppose if `${x}` isdictionary and has the value `{'a':'4','b':'3'}`. Please see the below code. I am getting error after incrementing the value. And the type of this variable ${count} is 'int' before and after increment.

```
${count}=       set variable    3
Dictionary Should Contain Value      ${x}       ${count}  ##--------> True
${Count}=    Evaluate    ${Count}+1
Dictionary Should Contain Value      ${x}}       ${count}  ##-------> Doesnot contain value '4'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variable `${count}` is at the beginning not an integer. It is string.
Integer has to be set like this in Robot Framework
`${count}=    set variable    ${3}`

After your `Evaluate` you have an integer because `3+1` evaluates to `4`

You dictionary has strings as values. `{'a':'4','b':'3'}`
So the first call works, because you expect the string `"3"` in the dictionary.
The second call failed, because the integer `4` ins not equal to the string `"4"`

This code would work:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
&{x}              a=4    b=3

*** Test Cases ***
test
    ${count}=    set variable    3
    Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${x}    ${count}
    ${Count}=    Evaluate    str(${Count}+1)
    Dictionary Should Contain Value    ${x}    ${count}
```